# How do I add filter with woocommerce categories?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, loop

I have created a loop that displays products, however I have ran into a problem when trying to filter them. I have added in tax_query because that is how to filter the search with taxonomies(based on my understanding). I have obtained the current urls term to filter with `$term_search = get_queried_object()->slug;` and I have echo'd out $term_search to make sure it was outputing the correct information.

How do I get my filter to work properly? One thing to mention, I have changed my permalink for the categories, does that effect my slug?

```
                $term_search = get_queried_object()->slug;
                // WP_Query arguments
                $args = array(
                    'p'                      => 'product',
                    'post_type'              => array( 'product' ),
                    'order'                  => 'ASC',
                    'post_per_page' => 20,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term_search, // (the name of what you want to filter by (latest or whatever))
                        'include_children' => true,
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                        ),
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the condition for the array inside the tax_query array. It is important to have it regardless if you have one or more conditions.

```
  $term_search = get_queried_object()->slug;
                // WP_Query arguments
                $args = array(
                    'p'                      => 'product',
                    'post_type'              => array( 'product' ),
                    'order'                  => 'ASC',
                    'post_per_page' => 20,
                    'tax_query' => array(array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term_search, // (the name of what you want to filter by (latest or whatever))
                        'include_children' => true,
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                        )),
                );
```

Comment: And apart from that tax query, it's `posts_per_page` (note the plural "posts") and not `post_per_page`. Also, you do not need that `p` which should be a post ID - it's ignored when it's not an integer, though, hence your query would still work.

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes I just removed those about 10 minutes ago. I copied those from another place thinking they were required, but they didn't do anything for my query. Thank you :)